how to test the media format compatibility on android?
I want to test if my android device support reading all media data format (mp3, mp4, MPEC) via USB. Can you please give me some tips how to do it easily?
I image to put all format on a usb and to open it. I find the something like Android CTS, is that good for my purpose? At lease to get all of possible test Audio video files?

Yes,
You can use android-cts ( Media modules ) to check the compatibility, Please be more specific on what you want to test here ( Concurrent playbacks, stress testing over certain codecs or just simply playback of multiple codecs ).
android-cts will have pre-written test cases by google to do it and it will take care of everything, right from downloading media files, pushing the test APK and running it, Please check this -> https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/cts

Hey, thank you for your anser. So basically I want to test Concurrent playbacks and playback of multiple codecs.  So I download the cts files and i see a lot of music files, however it contains not all mentioned on this site: https://developer.android.com/media/platform/supported-formats.  Is there some reason that cts 1.4 do not test all of them? Greeting
